# How to set multiple columns in a data table to values from different columns in the same data table?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data frame with 6 columns, and I want to set col 1:3 to the values in col 4:6 (this comes up a lot when merging). With data frames it's easy:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100,30),ncol=6))
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# 1 27 86 19 43 75 29
# 2 37 97 16 88 17  1
# 3 57 62 61 83 51 28
# 4 89 58 34 32 10 81
# 5 20  6 67 63 21 25

df[,1:3] <- df[,4:6]                    # very, very straightforward...
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# 1 43 75 29 43 75 29
# 2 88 17  1 88 17  1
# 3 83 51 28 83 51 28
# 4 32 10 81 32 10 81
# 5 63 21 25 63 21 25
```

With data.tables, not so much:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,1:3,with=F] <- dt[,4:6,with=F]
## Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , 1:3, with = F, value = list(X4 = c(43L,  : unused argument (with = F)
```

This works, but seems extremely complicated for such a simple transformation:

```
dt[, names(dt)[1:3]:=dt[,4:6,with=F]]   # very, very complicated...
dt
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# 1: 43 75 29 43 75 29
# 2: 88 17  1 88 17  1
# 3: 83 51 28 83 51 28
# 4: 32 10 81 32 10 81
# 5: 63 21 25 63 21 25
```

**The question** is: is there a simpler way to assign one set of columns in a data table to the values from another set of columns in the same data table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `:=` operator and name column numbers in `.SD`:

```
dt[, 1:3 := .SD, .SDcols = 4:6]

> dt
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1: 43 75 29 43 75 29
2: 88 17  1 88 17  1
3: 83 51 28 83 51 28
4: 32 10 81 32 10 81
5: 63 21 25 63 21 25
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a for loop would look better?

```
for (i in 1:3) dt[[i]] = dt[[i+3]]
```

Comment: This'll make a copy. Use `set`. `for (i in 1:3) set(dt, i=NULL, j=i, value=dt[[i+3]])`.

Comment: @Arun sure but I thought the goal of OP was simplicity, not efficiency

Comment: My take was "simple" without losing the advantages of using a data.table. Otherwise, why use "data.table" in the first place..?

Comment: I can come up with many many reasons for that "why" :) Anyway, looks like OP got what they wanted.

Comment: @Arun's take is correct. I accept that data tables require named columns unless you include `with=F`, and that using `:=` is preferred so the table is not copied. I was surprised, though, by the fact that `dt[,1:3,with=F]` on the LHS is not allowed. This seems very counter intuitive. Basically, I tried everything except using `with=F` twice. Figures...