# How to set multiple columns and selected rows in data table to value from other data table

Tags: r, data.table

The Question is somewhat related with this question ([How to set multiple columns in a data table to values from different columns in the same data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383233/how-to-set-multiple-columns-in-a-data-table-to-values-from-different-columns-in)).

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100,30),ncol=6))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1 27 86 19 43 75 29
#2 37 97 16 88 17  1
#3 57 62 61 83 51 28
#4 89 58 34 32 10 81
#5 20  6 67 63 21 25
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)


df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100,30),ncol=6))
df1
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1  49 64 74 68 39  8
#2  60 75 58  2 88 24
#3 100 11 69 40 35 91
#4  19 67 98 61 97 48
#5  80 38 46 57  6 29
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
```

This time, I want to change the certain row and column.

```
dt[1:3, c("X1","X2"), with = F] = dt1[1:3, c("X3","X5"), with = F]
```

But this one give an error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 1:3, c("X1", "X2"), with = F, value = list( : 
  unused argument (with = F)
```

I will do with the data had many columns. I hope that the name of column should be character at first.

Comment: `dt[1:3, c("V1","V2") := dt1[1:3, c("V3","V5"), with = FALSE], with = FALSE]` I think will do it. You've just confused `=` for `:=` and not executed the function inside `dt[...]`

Comment: Your solution also gives an error: `Error in [.data.table(dt1, 1:3, c("V3", "V5"), with = FALSE) : 
  column(s) not found: V3, V5`. Did you check the answer?

Comment: You might want to change the `V`'s to `X`'s for your example data. A slight adaptation of @thelatemail's comment (the second `with = FALSE` is not needed): `dt[1:3, c("X1","X2") := dt1[1:3, c("X3","X5"), with = FALSE]]`

Comment: @jaap This is the answer i want. Thank you

Comment: @asbebe ok, added as an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `=` operator as you do, you are trying assign the values to the desired spots in the *data.table*. Instead you should update your *data.table* `dt` by reference with the `:=` operator inside `dt[...]`. A slight adaptation of @thelatemail's comment (the second `with = FALSE` is not needed):

```
dt[1:3, c("X1","X2") := dt1[1:3, c("X3","X5"), with = FALSE]]
```