# "object 'ansvals' not found" error - what does it mean?

Tags: r, data.table

from my simple data.table, for example, like this:

```
dt1 <- fread("
col1 col2 col3
AAA  ab   cd
BBB  ef   gh
BBB  ij   kl
CCC  mn   nm")
```

I am making new table, for example, like this:

```
dt1[,
    .(col3, new=.N),
    by=col1]

>   col1 col3 new
>1:  AAA   cd   1
>2:  BBB   gh   2
>3:  BBB   kl   2
>4:  CCC   op   1
```

this works fine when I indicate column names explicitly. But when I have them in the variables and try to use `with=F`, this gives an error:

```
colBy   <- 'col1'
colShow <- 'col3' 

dt1[,
    .(colShow, 'new'=.N),
    by=colBy,
    with=F] 
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , .(colShow, new = .N), by = colBy, with = F) :   object 'ansvals' not found
```

I could not find any information about this error so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error message is that when using `with=FALSE` you tell *data.table* to treat `j` as if it were a dataframe. It therefore expects a vector of columnnames and not an expression to be evaluated in `j` as `new=.N`.

From the documentation of `?data.table` about `with`:

> By default `with=TRUE` and j is evaluated within the frame of x; column
>   names can be used as variables. When `with=FALSE` j is a character
>   vector of column names or a numeric vector of column positions to
>   select, and the value returned is always a data.table.

When you use `with=FALSE`, you have to select the columnnames in `j` without a `.` before `()` like this: `dt1[, (colShow), with=FALSE]`. Other options are `dt1[, c(colShow), with=FALSE]` or `dt1[, colShow, with=FALSE]`. The same result can be obtained by using `dt1[, .(col3)]`

To sum up: `with = FALSE` is used to select columns the *data.frame* way. So, you should do it then as such.

Also by using `by = colBy` you are telling *data.table* to evaluate `j` which is in contradiction with `with = FALSE`.

From the documentation of `?data.table` about `j`:

> A single column name, single expresson of column names, `list()` of
>   expressions of column names, an expression or function call that
>   evaluates to list (including data.frame and data.table which are
>   lists, too), or (when `with=FALSE`) a vector of names or positions to
>   select.
>
> `j` is evaluated within the frame of the data.table; i.e., it
>   sees column names as if they are variables. Use `j=list(...)` to return
>   multiple columns and/or expressions of columns. A single column or
>   single expression returns that type, usually a vector. See the
>   examples.

See also points [***1.d*** and ***1.g*** of the introduction vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) of *data.table*.

---

`ansvals` is a name used in *data.table* internals. You can see where it appears in the code by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (macOS) [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R).

Comment: thank you for explanation! Does it actually mean that there's just no way to use `by=` when column names are stored in variables?

Comment: @VasilyA That's certainly possible, but you have to do it in the correct way. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940580/convert-some-column-classes-in-data-table/32942319#32942319) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772830/how-to-set-multiple-columns-and-selected-rows-in-data-table-to-value-from-other/33774525#33774525) for examples. You might also want to read the [getting started guide](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: well, in those examples `by=` is not used at all, this makes it quite different... I will read again the Getting started guide and maybe post a separate question specifying what exactly I need.

Answer (score 1):

The error `object 'ansvals' not found` looks like a bug to me. It should either be a helpful message or just work. I've filed [issue #1440](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1440) linking back to this question, thank you.

Jaap is completely correct.  Following on from his answer, you can use `get()` in `j` like this :

```
dt1
#   col1 col2 col3
#1:  AAA   ab   cd
#2:  BBB   ef   gh
#3:  BBB   ij   kl
#4:  CCC   mn   nm
colBy
#[1] "col1"
colShow
#[1] "col3"
dt1[,.(get(colShow),.N),by=colBy]
#   col1 V1 N
#1:  AAA cd 1
#2:  BBB gh 2
#3:  BBB kl 2
#4:  CCC nm 1
```

Comment: thank you Matt! I was just going to post a question asking if `get()` could be a good solution :)